# Can giving same variable names to actual and formal parameters in C++ create any problems?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Can giving the same name to formal parameters in the called functions as the actual parameters in the calling function create any problems while passing by *reference*?

Also, would it be any different while passing by value?

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: C++ controls scope very well.  Names always refer to the in the current scope.  A reference is often in practicality of a function call turned into a pointer.  A compiled program doesn't care what you called a variable.  What does your compiler say? Does it complain about multiple definitions?

Comment: Others answered, but I think it is a good practice to use the same name while passing a variable by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: params]

If you are talking about stuff in picture, simple answer is it does not matter at all. In "pass by value" case, value of caller function is copied to the address of parameter of called function.

When it comes to references, here is one quote:

> A reference shares the same memory address with the original variable but also takes up some space on the stack whereas a pointer has its own memory address and size on the stack.

So to simplify the answer, parameter and local variable names do not matter much because compiler converts them into addresses. As seen from above, even reference has to store the address of referred variable.

My suggestion is [read this](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/passing-arguments-by-value/). And think of variables or parameters in term of addresses, not in terms of their names.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the example:

```
void foo(int& arg1, int arg2)
{
}

void bar()
{
    int   arg1 = 4;
    int   arg2 = 2;
    foo(arg1, arg2);
}
```

No, such code will not cause any problem. The scopes of those variables are disjoint, none of them can potentially hide another (or did you mean some other potential problem?).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are asking if it's ok use the same name for actual parameters and formal parameters. It won't cause any problems as far as I know whichever you choose pass-by-value or pass-by-reference. The scope of formal parameters' name is their function (let's say its name is `f`), and the scope of actual parameters' name is the function which calls the function f. So they won't interfere each other.

Answer (score 0):

Straight Forward answer to your very first question is YES,you can do that
But it degrades the readability of codes and creates mess while compiling the code in your mind or practice book, because it is recommended to check the program (if possible) to compile and execute with some test case without machine i.e. compiler on your mind or notebook.
(From a ICPC world finalist's point of view)
So avoid giving same names.